Java: How to prevent non-top level annotations on type?
Java: How to prevent non-top level annotations on type? e.g.,
@Target(value={ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FooList {
    public Foo[] value();
}


@Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Foo {
    public String name();
}

@FooList({
     @Foo(name="ABC"),
     @Foo(name="XyZ")
})
@Foo(name="EFG")   // no compile error here
public class Bar {
}

@Foo should be inside @FooList only. But no compile error when @Foo is annotated on type Bar directly.

What does it mean when @Target is not present?
From the documentation of @Target:

If an @Target meta-annotation is not present on an annotation interface T, then an annotation of type T may be written as a modifier for any declaration.

And from §9.6.4.1 - Target of the Java Language Specification:

If an annotation of type java.lang.annotation.Target is not present on the declaration of an annotation interface A, then A is applicable in all declaration contexts and in no type contexts.

How to define an annotation that's not applicable in any context?
From the documentation of @Target:

This @Target meta-annotation indicates that the declared class or interface is intended solely for use as a member class or interface in complex annotation interface declarations. It cannot be used to annotate anything directly:
@Target({})
public @interface MemberInterface {
    ...
}


In short, meta-annotate your @Foo annotation with @Target({}).

Is @Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) needed when it is member of another annotation @Target({})? Thanks.

It's not needed. From the documentation of @Retention: "A Retention meta-annotation has effect only if the meta-annotated interface is used directly for annotation. It has no effect if the meta-annotated interface is used as a member interface in another annotation interface."
